# DEP compliant visual studio application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

i am developing an application in visual studio 2010 c#, i am using some 3rd party controls that interact with hardware. The problem i am facing is that DEP (Data Execution Prevention) is not allowing my application to run or call that DLL/ APIs that interact with hardware.

My Application is deployed on windows 7, any one please guide how i can make my application DEP compliant or how i can avoid DEP.

Comment: I think this is actually an excellent question and Should not be closed. Since it is closed, I don't think I can post an answer. But, here is a comment that I hope helps. Please see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ed_maurer/2007/12/13/nxcompat-and-the-c-compiler/. By default, C# applications opt-in to DEP. When building a mixed application with native controls or DLLs, you must change the PE flags on your EXE file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is of course not the right place to find support for unnamed "3rd party controls", contact their owner or vendor.  .NET compilers mark the executables they generate as DEP compatible since .NET 2.0 SP1.  The only option you'll have if you can't get these controls updated is to mark your program as not compatible.

You need to do so in a post build event that edits the executable header.  Project + Properties, Build events and paste this in the Post build event command line box:

```
  set path=%path%;$(DevEnvDir);$(DevEnvDir)..\..\vc\bin
  editbin.exe /NOLOGO /NXCOMPAT:NO "$(TargetPath)"
```

Comment: Thanks @Hans i also read some where that it can be done by using /NXCOMPAT:NO but could not find how to use it. Can you please explain steps involved ? where to write this command ? which values i have to change in this command?

Comment: I was pretty explicit about the menu commands you use.  Project + Properties, etcetera.  Don't change anything.  Have you actually tried this?

Comment: Not yet tried, i was asking about changing "..\..\vc\bin\editbin.exe " and TargetPath? do i have to change these

Comment: I stumps me what could possibly be unclear about "Don't change anything".

Comment: i tried but there is an exception while compilation "'editbin.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: You'll need to find it back in the vc\bin subdirectory of the Visual Studio install directory.  You cannot make this work if you have the Express edition.

Comment: right after getting this error message i browsed the vc folder and editbin.exe is there.

Comment: I faced a similar issue. One think i would like to add here. Apart from what hans answer mentions, you need to stop using the Visual Studio hosting process while running in VS. Then only you can directly run it successfully from VS. To do so -> Select project and right click to Show Properties -> Debug tab -> Uncheck the "Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process".

Comment: I missed something, I dont doubt Hans, but if this is not working you may want to have a look at http://jtstroup.net/post/Attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-This-is-often-an-indication-that-other-memory-is-corrupt.aspx  I think It will work as it works for me. Then you need to have a look at my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks @Dinesh you should post your comments as answer, they are very helpful.